# fastest mechanism to return large data from a micro-service

Tags: json, rest, http, redis, microservices

I am new to the micro-service world.

My micro-service has to return a large data (ballpark of 10-20 Mb).
The returned data contains **large 2D arrays** ("images") and **small structured data** that can easily be represented with Json.

Important: Both client and server are **on the same machine**.

I have few options to return the data:

1. Encode the data to bytes array and send in the **post** body.
2. Encode only the "images" to binary and **"multi-part" post** json + binary image1 + ... + binary imageN.
3. Write the data to a **server resources** (memory?)
   and send the urls to client. The client will fetch the data with
   few **GET** commands.
4. Write the data to **Redis DB** and send the client the
   Redis address and data keys. The client will fetch the data with few
   Redis readings.

What is **fastest** and the industry **best known method** to send back the results?

Comment: Do you control the microservice only? This really smells like an IPC problem ...

Comment: control the client too. Sure, this is an ipc domain question.

Comment: Then I just have to ask why you would bother with the overhead of TCP/IP and HTTP at all. Shared memory or temporary files were the way to go.

Comment: My client is Web so HTTP is natural choice + I want to keep the option for scaling up to distributed environment.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around this and need some clarification: In *which* direction is *what* data going? And are those images renderable (i.e. pictures) or just raw binary data?

Comment: Thanks @DaSourcerer. Data is going from server to web client (currently both on same machine with option to distributed, thus http is preferred). "Images" are raw binary data (which also can be represented as non-compress-able image format like uint8 tiff)

Answer (score 1):

Based on our experience in software architecture (> 20 years), there should be 2 distinct APIs:

- **API for Meta-data** — API will provide information about images and links to images.
- **API for Image Download** — Separate API for downloading images. It can also support bulk download (as archive) considering network latency. This can leverage in-memory database like Redis DB or similar to provide quicker response time.